# setText : is deprecated

Tags: ios, xcode4, deprecated, settext

i tryed to learn how working with a sql data source, i've find a sample name SQLiteTutorial in apple's sample
What bad, apple did not update their samples, so when i open apple sample file i've got many deprecated warning ....

in that case the code is

```
// Set up the cell
    SQLiteTutorialAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SQLiteTutorialAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    Animal *animal = (Animal *)[appDelegate.animals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell setText:animal.name];
    return cell;
```

and Xcode said me setText is deprecated, but i did not find how to correct this.

The tutorial i'm working on is here : http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/

I've got other warning in the app delegate

```
// Execute the "checkAndCreateDatabase" function
    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];

    // Query the database for all animal records and construct the "animals" array
    [self readAnimalsFromDatabase];

    // Configure and show the window
    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Xcode tell me that SQLiteTutorialAppDelegate may not respond to checkAndCreateDatabase and to readAnimalsFromDatabase

and the last thing in the RootViewController , instance method initWithData:cache not found

[image]

```
/ Load the animals image into a NSData boject and then assign it to the UIImageView
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[animal imageURL]]];




    UIImage *animalImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData cache:YES];
    self.animalView.animalImage.image = animalImage;

}
```

thanks if you have an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cell.textLabel.text = animal.name;
```

Is how you set text in the cell since iOS 3.0.

Don't know about other warning because they are related to the code You didn't post. Learning from such old code is not a good idea, you should probably find something slightly newer :)

Comment: thanks for your answer, it's clear so. In their answers many people forgot that english is not my native language and the fact that i'm beginner, sometimes their answer are chinese for me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/text) is always a good start to look for how to replace deprecated methods:

> The text of the cell. (Deprecated in iOS 3.0. Use the textLabel and
>   detailTextLabel properties instead.)

As for your other warnings, you've probably forgotten to declare the `readAnimalsFromDatabase` and `checkAndCreateDatabase` methods in your header file.